# Search for 2 of the largest numbers - the largest, and the one next-to-largest C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm beginner in C++ and I have a homework that I stumbled on.
I have to find the largest and the second largest number **without using arrays or vectors** , only if or while statement. I would be more than happy if anyone shows me how to do it. :)

this is my program so far ( I managed to find the largest and the smallest )

`

```
std::cout << "Insert five numbers: " << std::endl;
    int num1{};
    int num2{};
    int num3{};
    int num4{};
    int num5{};
    std::cin >> num1 >> num2 >> num3 >> num4 >> num5;
    std::cout << '\n';
    
    // Find the largest number : 
    if ((num1 > num2) && (num1 > num3) && (num1 > num4) && (num1 > num5))
    {
        std::cout << "Number One " << "(" << (num1)<< ")" << " is the largest number !" << std::endl;
    }
    if ((num2 > num1) && (num2 > num3) && (num2 > num4) && (num2 > num5))
    {
        std::cout << "Number Two " << "(" << (num2) << ")" << "is the largest number !" << std::endl;
    }
    if ((num3 > num1) && (num3 > num2) && (num3 > num4) && (num3 > num5))
    {
        std::cout << "Number Three" << "(" << (num3) << ")" << " is the largest number !" << std::endl;
    }
    if ((num4 > num1) && (num4 > num2) && (num4 > num3) && (num4 > num5))
    {
        std::cout << "Number Four" << "(" << (num4) << ")" << " is the largest number !" << std::endl;
    }
    if ((num5 > num1) && (num5 > num2) && (num5 > num3) && (num5 > num4))
    {
        std::cout << "Number Five" << "(" << (num5) << ")" << " is the largest number !" << std::endl;
    }

    //Find the smallest number :
    if ((num1 < num2) && (num1 < num3) && (num1 < num4) && (num1 < num5))
    {
        std::cout << "Number One" << "(" << (num1) << ")" << " is the smallest number !" << std::endl;
    }
    if ((num2 < num1) && (num2 < num3) && (num2 < num4) && (num2 < num5))
    {
        std::cout << "Number Two" << "(" << (num2) << ")" << " is the smallest number !" << std::endl;
    }
    if ((num3 < num1) && (num3 < num2) && (num3 < num4) && (num3 < num5))
    {
        std::cout << "Number Three" << "(" << (num3) << ")" << " is the smallest number !" << std::endl;
    }
    if ((num4 < num1) && (num4 < num2) && (num4 < num3) && (num4 < num5))
    {
        std::cout << "Number Four" << "(" << (num4) << ")" << " is the smallest number !" << std::endl;
    }
    if ((num5 < num1) && (num5 < num2) && (num5 < num3) && (num5 < num4))
    {
        std::cout << "Number Five" << "(" << (num5) << ")" << " is the smallest number !" << std::endl;
    }
```

`

Comment: `without using arrays` - well that sucks ;)

Comment: But still possible right?

Comment: Sure. One possibility that comes to mind is to first compare num1 to every other number, as you do, but then swap them whenever what you compare to is greater, so that after having compared to (and possibly swapped with) every other value, num1 is the largest. Then you do the same for num2 through 5 to find the second largest.

Comment: As a student you should not get a fully coded answer. You should be able to do this from the suggestion make a loop and keep only the current largest and second-largest number. Then you input your number, do your checks and iterate.

Comment: It is most convenient to set up two variables to store the largest and second largest numbers. Since this is homework, it is recommended that you implement the code details yourself. Idea: By default, the first number is the maximum value. Compare the second number with the first number to get the current maximum value and the second largest number. Compare the next number to both variables and update the new largest and second largest numbers. So on...

Answer (score 1):

You could keep the maximum and the second maximum along you read your input numbers.

I've started reading the first number outside the loop, and setting `max_n` to it, because it simplifies the code within the loop.

Notice `while (counter--)` will check `counter` at the beginning of the loop, enter the loop if `counter` is non-zero, and then decrement it. So you'll end up reading `counter` numbers (4) in the loop.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/9zr7rjv4a)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Insert five numbers: \n";
    constexpr auto min_int{ std::numeric_limits<int>::min() };
    int max_n{ min_int };
    int second_max_n{ min_int };    
    std::cin >> max_n;  // set max_n to first number
    int counter { 4 };  // then read the other 4
    while (counter--) {
        int n{};
        std::cin >> n;
        if (n > max_n) {  // a new max is found, update both max and second max
            second_max_n = max_n;
            max_n = n;
        } else if (n != max_n and n > second_max_n) {  // maybe a new second max?
            second_max_n = n;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "max: " << max_n << ", second max: " << second_max_n;
}


// Input: 75 0 100 -50 100
// Output: max: 100, second max: 75
```

---

The code as it is finds the second largest number different to the largest. Would you let both numbers be the same, you should get rid of the `n != max_n` comparison in the `else if`.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/ovbe5xhv5)

Comment: I tried your program, but it keeps giving me to insert numbers. How do I fix that ?

Comment: Sorry about that! I updated the answer so that it only reads 5 numbers.